# C++ | Какой компилятор нужен в VSC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Как мне запустить код C++ в Visual Studio Code?

Comment: [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я это пробовал не запускает он код

Comment: Когда С++ пытаюсь запустить пишет компилятор не найден

Comment: одного расширения недостаточно, нужно ещё и компилятор ставить. Мне кажется, что clang - самое простое решение.

Comment: Так и пишет, "компилятор не найден"? Покажите точную ошибку.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler